# Git remote server none-bare without user

Tags: git, push, git-bare

Ok, check this out. I have a mac osx server with git installed. We use it for collaborating on projects. What we want is to be able to push to none-bare repository on the server so that we can view the websites on it. The problem is, a none-bare repository has a user with the master checked out, so were not able to push to the master.

The only way I have found working is to push to another branch and then merge it into the master branch, thats time-consuming and boring.

So, is there a way to push to the master branch on the remote server and be able to view the webpage on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to deal with this is to have a bare repository with a hook that will checkout `HEAD` to the correct directory, [as described here](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto).  Essentially, you would create a `post-receive` hook that does:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/whatever git checkout -f
```

Then you just push to that bare repository in order to deploy.  This method the advantage over pushing to a non-bare repository that you won't end up with a `.git` directory under `/var/www/whatever`, just the files in your project.

Comment: ok, say I wan't to have the files in a folder that is in same folder that the git repository is in. in my case the folder where my repository is in is named xsessions, the folder I want the files to be deployed is xsessions/www . how would I write this in the post-receive hook?

Comment: Do you mean you want the files to be deployed to `xsessions/www`?  Otherwise I don't understand your first sentence...

Comment: Sorry, yes I want the files to be deployed to xsessions/www

Comment: Ok, I made it :D all I had forgotten vas to chmod the post-receive file
    chmod +x hooks/post-receive